How do you write an extension method with a `where` clause for the `Predicate<each Input>` type in SwiftData?
In SwiftData, the Predicate type makes use of parameter packs:
struct Predicate<each Input>

Now, I want to add an extension method on Predicate which is only available if the generic parameter is of type SomeType:
@Model
class SomeType {
    var someVar: Int
}

I've been trying to get it working, but it gives various errors:
extension Predicate where Input == SomeType { }


Pack reference 'Input' requires expansion using keyword 'repeat'


Type pack 'Input' must be referenced with 'each'

extension Predicate where each Input == SomeType { }


Pack reference 'Input' requires expansion using keyword 'repeat'

extension Predicate where repeat each Input == (SomeType) { }


Same-element requirements are not yet supported

How can I add this function as a static func on Predicate<each Input> where Input == SomeType?
static func predicateMatchingNegativeSomeVars() -> Predicate<SomeType> {
    #Predicate<SomeType> {
        $0.someVar < 0
    }
}


SE-0393 actually mentions a syntax similar to what you attempted in the Future Directions section. This hasn't been implemented at the moment.
But thanks to SE-361, you can just do
extension Predicate<SomeType> {
    static func predicateMatchingNegativeSomeVars() -> Predicate<SomeType> {
        #Predicate<SomeType> {
            $0.someVar < 0
        }
    }
}

That said, since the method you want to add is static anyway, you don't need this bound - just write extension Predicate { ... } instead. You only need this if you are adding instance members.

However this does show up during code complete for Predicates where Input is not SomeType.

@iSpain17 Huh, interesting. It's probably just the language server not understanding parameter packs, unrelated to the syntax used to declare the extension.
